# Unable to run 8 video cards GeoForce GTX 1060 on Windows 10 machine

Tags: windows

About a month ago I built my [mining farm with Windows 10 Pro and 8 video cards GeoForce GTX 1060](https://developernote.com/2018/02/setting-up-asus-prime-h270-plus-motherboard-for-gpu-mining/), and it worked for some time.

But after a Windows 10 update was automatically installed and the system was rebooted, Windows 10 found only 4 video cards (it shows only 4 cards in Device Manager/Display Adapters, and mining software works only with 4 cards).

I have an impression that something was changed in Windows 10, because I did not change driver, BIOS settings, etc.. What Windows setting can affect this?

```
MB: ASUS PRIME H270-PLUS
CPU: Intel Celeron
RAM: 4GB

BIOS settings:

Advanced\System Agent (SA) Configuration
Above 4G decoding [Disabled] -> [Enabled]
DMI/OPT Configuration\DMI Max Link Speed [Auto] -> [Gen1]
PEG Port Configuration\PCIEX16_1 Link Speed [Auto] -> [Gen1]
Advanced\PCH Configuration
PCI Express Configuration\PCIe Speed [Auto] -> [Gen1]
Advanced\APM Configuration
Restore AC Power Loss [Power Off]->[Last State]
Advanced\Onboard Devices Configuration
HD Audio Controller [Enabled]->[Disabled]
M.2_1 Configuration [Auto]->[PCIE]
M.2_2 Configuration [Auto]->[PCIE]
```

Comment: How are you loading 8 video cards into a motherboard that only has two full-length slots? That could be a very relevant piece of information.

Comment: I use adapters (6 pci-e raises + 2 M2 adapters). The most miners use them on their farms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not a Windows problem, raisers power cable was damaged.